# Python3.4+Flask+Celery+Gevent+[Flask-]SQLAlchemy+Psycopg2 memory leak?

Tags: python-3.x, celery, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2, gevent

I have following stack Python3.4+Flask+Celery+Gevent+[Flask-]SQLAlchemy+Psycopg2 and there is a problem with celery worker memory usage.

1. Celery beat execution (it queues tasks every 10 seconds):

`$ celery beat -A some_module -l info`

2. Celery worker execution (every task takes ~5 second):

`$ celery worker -c 1000 -P gevent -l info -A some_module`

That's ok! But after 2-3 days uptime celery worker uses 90% of memory.

The task is simple: we fetch json data from some REST API service (`requests` package) and store it to postgresql DB (`flask_sqlalchemy` package).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you please share code.

Comment: Your stack is rather OK - you can verify this by using "empty" tasks. Take a look your code, the first potential place for leaking, the second is a weak version of some library.